# Why Items from first page in ArrayList are deleted when I go to page2?

Tags: android, arraylist, observable, observers, subscribe

I am building an app and I use Arraylist, which is emmited from Observable. In that list I have 20 items. First 10 items are on page 1 and second 10 items are on page 2. But, when I go on page 2, the first 10 items are deleted, and it is shown only 10 items from page 2, but I don't what that. I want to show all that 20 items on page 2, not only that 10 items from page 2.
Could you help me?

This is my code:

```
ideaService.getIdeas(page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        if (ideaAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                            ideaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            //ideaAdapter.setLoaded();

                           // startingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //mRecycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                    startingText.setText(getString(R.string.no_ideas));
                }
                if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                ideaAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        dialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ArrayList<Item> items) {
                        //Remove loading item
                        //ideaAdapter.getmItems().remove(ideaAdapter.getmItems().size() - 1);
                        //ideaAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(ideaAdapter.getmItems().size());
                        ideaAdapter.clear();
                        ideaAdapter.setList(items);
                        Log.d("Array", "arrayListONE " + ideaAdapter.getmItems().size());

                    }
                });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is in callback `onNext();`
you are doing this

```
ideaAdapter.clear();
ideaAdapter.setList(items);
```

I don't know what type of `adapter` you have but, You can guess what will happen if you are asking to clear the `Adapter`

if you are using [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29), `clear()` method will remove all elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
@Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<Item> items) {
                    //Remove loading item
                    //ideaAdapter.getmItems().remove(ideaAdapter.getmItems().size() - 1);
                    //ideaAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(ideaAdapter.getmItems().size());
                    ideaAdapter.clear(); 
                    // if your items list is of 20 items only
                    ideaAdapter.setList(items.subList(10,19));
                    ideaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.d("Array", "arrayListONE " + ideaAdapter.getmItems().size());

                }
```

Comment: What if I have for example 50 items(10 items per page)?

Comment: Have some id based approach so you can subList array list properly